# How can I set default_currency= "INR" in settings.py file because its use many times in project?

Tags: django, model, settings, currency, money-format

I want to save MoneyField details in setting.py file so I can use it every places where I use MoneyField I want to save this..

```
MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='INR', null=False, default=0.0)
```

How can save it in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

Django uses a setting named **`DEFAULT_CURRENCY`** to set the currency, the default is `'XYZ'`. Indeed, if we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/blob/0.15.x/djmoney/models/fields.py#L169), we see:

```
from ..settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES, DECIMAL_PLACES, DEFAULT_CURRENCY

# …

class MoneyField(models.DecimalField):
    # …

    def __init__(
        self,
        # ...,
        default_currency=DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
        # …
    ):
        # …
    
    # …
```

You thus can set the `DEFAULT_CURRENCY` in the `settings.py` to:

```
# settings.py

# …

DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'INR'

# …
```

and the omit the `default_currency='INR'` parameters when you create `MoneyField`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of `functools.partial` to do this.

```py
from functools import partial

from django.db import models

MyMoneyField = partial(
    models.DecimalField,
    default='INR',
    ...
)
```

Now you can use this in the form:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    amount = MyMoneyField()
```

In case, you want this to be configurable via your `settings`, just set `DEFAULT_CURRENCY` to `INR` in your `settings.py`, and then use it in the form:

```py
from django.conf import settings

MyMoneyField = partial(
    models.DecimalField,
    default=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
    ...
)
```

`partial` also allows use to replace the previously filled argument. For example:

```py
class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    new_amount = MyMoneyField(current='USD')
```